# Show an abbreviation \ac{*} abbreviated in the first use

Tags: acronyms

I'm using `\ac{m}` for meters, but I don't want it to be shown in the long way at first use. How can it be shown only abbreviated?

Comment: only use `\acs{m}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @cgnieder said it's `\acs{}`.